# Is there a code editor that will allow copying of syntax highlighting to an Office Document for Windows?

Tags: ms-word, editor, syntax-highlighting, copy-paste

Is there a code editor that will allow copying of syntax highlighting to an Office Document for Windows?

I want to be able to copy code into a Word doc or EMail and preserve the Formatting when explaing code changes.

I will need support for multiple languages including C, C++, TCL, Javascript, Basic, and couple others.

The ability to include the line numbers for reference purposes would be a nice additional feature.  I had one customer that required all code to be submitted with line numbers in a Word or PDF document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Notepad++ in the past. It has a plug-in called NppExport and I think it has everything you need. The catch is that you have to write/open your source files with Notepad++, then export them to rtf, open the rtf and copy the pretty-formatted text to your doc file.
Here is the link to [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and to [a good article to get you started with NppExport](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/nppexport-for-notepad-export-highlighted-code-in-html-rtf-format/) plugin.

Comment: These days you can copy formatted code to the clipboard and then paste in Word.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio (2010 Professional) "works fine" for copying code and formatting/coloring to MS Word (2010) and Outlook (2010)*. It supports at least C/C++/C#, and JavaScript code. It might support TCL/BASIC (it does support VB/VB.NET), but I do not use those languages. And, of course, VS is a full-blown IDE.

[Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) is free (as in beer). But as my company pays for my copy, I can only *hope* the copy'n'paste support works in Express as well ;-) In any case, it might be worth a try.

I am not sure if line-numbers can be exported via copy'n'paste, but I sort of doubt it. It's not a use-case I've run into.

Personally, I'd recommend doing the review via a SCM/code-review process and *not* manually, which just sounds like a nightmare. There are additional advantages of using tooling designed for this purpose including history management and talking about what really is, or could be (in relation to what was), and not a copy of what might have been.

Happy coding.

---

*After pasting into Microsoft Word, disable the "Add space after every paragraph" option to remove what appears to be blank lines from the pasted code.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) will do fine if you install the language support for all the wanted languages.